# Object Cache - Avoid db queries totally

Tags: wpdb, cache, core-modifications

I am using object cache and have cached just about all queries but am stuck with the last 3, 
on a post archive page. They are all wp core queries.

1. SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wpm_posts.ID FROM wpm_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wpm_posts.post_type = 'cpt'  --->i believe this is the main query
2. SELECT FOUND_ROWS() --> empty query
3. SELECT comment_approved, COUNT( * ) AS num_comments FROM wpm_comments  GROUP BY comment_approved -->comments

Does anyone know how to cache the 1st query and remove the next two or cache without changing core files (from plugin onwards)?

Comment: I know that it will not respond to your question, but perhaps you should consider optimizing other things than the core of wordpress. It's quite dangerous to begin modifying the core behaviour, moreover when time comes for updates.
There are so many other things to optimize in a website. :) Regards,
Fabien.

Comment: thanks Fabien for your input, I agree there are a lot of things to optimize besides the sql queries but I was trying to avoid hitting the DB entirely and varnish wouldn't suit due to the difference in frequency of changes of information. But to anyone reading in future looking to optimize for heavy users I ended using varnish caching and found that had the best performance compared to object caching. It was cheaper to update the v cache rather than hold the info in object cache.